# Using a list of different generics in TypeScript without losing original type information

Tags: typescript, generics, types

We have the following simplified code where we want to have a function using a list of `BaseDescription`, where each `BaseDescription` is of a different kind.

Whenever something is returned from test, the type information should still contain the original type. In the example code we have type `Example`, so we want `result` to be of type `BaseDescription<Example>`.

```
type Base = {
  foo: string
};

type BaseDescription<T extends Base> = {
  bar: String,
  baz: () => T
};

const test = (baseDescriptions: BaseDescription<any>[]) => {
  return baseDescriptions[0];
};

type Example = Base & {
  qux: string
};

const description: BaseDescription<Example> = {
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: () => ({ foo: 'foo', qux: 'qux' })
};

const result = test([ description ]);
// result is of type BaseDescription<any>
// but we want BaseDescription<Example>
```

Things already tried:

- Using interfaces instead of types
- Trying to find the TypeScript equivalent of `<? extends Base>` (coming from Java)
- Trying to find raw types
- Using `<Base>`, but then result will have type `Base` instead of `Example`

Is the described behaviour even possible? And if so, how?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers so far! Defenitly makes me understand TS better.

I want to clarify the question a bit more. The idea is that an array of different Types is passed in. [I have craeted a new playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=67&pln=15&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAQgQwM6wLwwN7BjAZge3wC4YkQAnASwDsBzYAXwG5hRJZEUARKJAYyoQQlfNQA8AFRhQAHiCjUAJknjIoAPhjosOAEYJyJAMoUatADTYY+gF4kAFAEotmiYxbA+osjHk-0ktJyCsqqKOr2+ty8ApRCItRIJJxQPPyCwqKS6gDaALrOqJo6MORQIACu5NTWammx8d4szKzg0DAAojIIALYQADZoYbAAZJhWAI4VMiRkVHTurewwAPIgABZQ5F29A0MpMGMluv0Is6YLLZ7eIDCKMRkJyXUPcZniO32DmtpW+oYwADk-0Blj0CDsMCcLihGDwhBIgII+FBMCmMyB6MBMAYjkW10St3wGy29Ueome0XSbwSYjWm223S+Gi043BAOBBlBfwhDkKmnscORiORqJOZ0x02xuPxXkJMByeEo5DI5lIUDlihgeVZfhA9kV92pjWoauJDLJNNE2scLCAA)

Additions:

```
type Example = Base & {
  qux: string
};

type OtherExample = Base & {
  bla: string
};

const description: BaseDescription<Example> = {
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: () => ({ foo: 'foo', qux: 'qux' })
};

const otherDescription: BaseDescription<OtherExample> = {
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: () => ({ foo: 'foo', bla: 'qux' })
};

const [ first, second ] = test([ description, otherDescription ]);
```

I get the feeling that the thing that I want to achieve, will not be possible.

Comment: I've looked at your issue, and tried using generics for the test function rather than putting any in it (as this widens the type to basically anything hence the any as result). See here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAQgQwM6wLwwN7BjAZge3wC4YkQAnASwDsBzYAXwG5hRJZEUARKJAYyoQQlfNQA8AFRhQAHiCjUAJknjIoAPhjosOAEYJyJAMoUatADTYY+gF4kAFAEotmiYxbA+osjHk-0ktJyCsqqKOr2+ty8ApRCItRIJJxQPPyCwqKS6gDaALrOqJo6MORQIACu5NTWammx8d45AAx5LMys4NAwAKIyCAC2EAA2aGGwAGSYVgCOFTIkZFR07qxeiSAwijEZCcl1O3GZ4n2DIxpa03oGJADk+uS3ltd2ME4ubxh4hHcE+E8wOYLGC3IG3GAMRyrTzeTZlJAVYabdB+ED2HJbQ6NGoFJhAA

Answer (score 2):

Any widens your type to practically anything, hence the return type of test will be `BaseDescription<any>` as TypeScript has no information about the type at compile time. To achieve that the test function allows you to return the type which got passed in, make use of generics.

Especially: `<T extends YourInterface>`

For TypeScript to infer the type you can use something like this:

```js
const doSomething = <T extends YourParentInterface>(param: T) => param;

interface X extends YourParentInterface { x: string }

const someObjectInstanceOfX: X = { x: "bla", /* ... some other properties coming from the parent interface */ }

doSomething(someObjectInstanceOfX) // => has return type X
```

You can check the return type inside [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAQgQwM6wLwwN7BjAZge3wC4YkQAnASwDsBzYAXwG5hRJZEUARKJAYyoQQlfNQA8AFRhQAHiCjUAJknjIoAPhjosOAEYJyJAMoUatADTYY%20gF4kAFAEotmiYxbA%20osjHk-0ktJyCsqqKOr2%20ty8ApRCItRIJJxQPPyCwqKS6gDaALrOqJo6MORQIACu5NTWammx8d45AAx5LMys4NAwAKIyCAC2EAA2aGGwAGSYVgCOFTIkZFR07qxeiSAwijEZCcl1O3GZ4n2DIxpa03oGJADk%20uS3ltd2ME4ubxh4hHcE%20E8wOYLGC3IG3GAMRyrTzeTZlJAVYabdB%20ED2HJbQ6NGoFJhAA) below you'll find the solution (which is the same as in the Playground):

```js
type Base = {
  foo: string
};

type BaseDescription<T extends Base> = {
  bar: String,
  baz: () => T
};

const test = <T extends Base>(baseDescriptions: BaseDescription<T>[]) => {
  return baseDescriptions[0];
};

type Example = Base & {
  qux: string
};

const description: BaseDescription<Example> = {
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: () => ({ foo: 'foo', qux: 'qux' })
};

const result = test([ description ]);
```

Comment: Please put your code from playground into your answer.

Comment: This answer works for array of  specefic T (in this case example). It seems to break when adding different types of T in a single array. I will edit the original question as the comment is to short to add a playground.

Comment: Indeed, in order to fix this, @captain-yossarian has already prepared an answer. The solution is array inferring (which is pretty similar to this one). My assumption was, there will be only the same T's.

Answer (score 1):

@r3dst0rm 's answer is perfectly valid and should be accepted.

If you are interested in alternative way of inferring array elements you can consider next example (`[...R]`):

This trick will do the job:

```js
type Base = {
  foo: string
};

type BaseDescription<T extends Base> = {
  bar: String,
  baz: () => T
};

const test = <T extends Base, R extends BaseDescription<T>[]>(baseDescriptions: [...R]) => {
  return baseDescriptions[0];
};

type Example = Base & {
  qux: string
};

const description: BaseDescription<Example> = {
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: () => ({ foo: 'foo', qux: 'qux' })
};

const result = test([ description ]); // BaseDescription<Example>
```

You just need to infer all elements in the array  `<T extends Base, R extends BaseDescription<T>[]>(baseDescriptions: [...R])`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBSgMwPZ4BcUCwATgJYB2A5hgL4DcGGoksiEAIhAgMaUwwCnioAeACpQIAD2AQqAEwQckAPiipM2AEZwyxAMrlqNADRYoegF7EAFAEpNGiQ2YY%20o0lHnfUk6TkFZVUIMygAJUD5JRV4JB5%20QWFRSTUAbQBdNTs9BN4BCiERKgRidIA6KojMp2QNbSgyCGAAVzIqK05EwuKvdIAGTOYmFjZoAFEZOABbMAAbFFCoADJ0SwBHVpliUkpaNxZPUuAoRQLkkuJ47guilPEp2YWIDS1LPQMoAHJP74tdHBbFBHM4QWhcARiN98Hh-lAtjsfojvlB6A5Dh4vKdmghWvNTqhfMA7Okznc%20p1aowoAB6WmhHqXVJPOaLNQYIA)